# SharePoint Framework onchange method not called

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, sharepoint-framework

I'm new to SPFx and doing this plain Javascript web part to kick off things but have hit a read block.

I can't seem to figure out on how to properly call the `oncahnge` method on a search input:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search the data"onchange="this._clickedMe()"/>
```

This is the method it's calling:

```
  private _clickedMe() {
    console.log('clicked Me');
  }
```

I also can't find the documents except for a few concept pages on MS devs site. 
Feel free to ask me any question to clear it up for you.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/sharepoint-crud/src/webparts

Answer (score 0):

That's only a convention. The `JavaScript` language does not give any special meaning to identifiers starting with underscore characters.

That said, it's quite a useful convention for a language that doesn't support [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) out of the box. Although there is no way to prevent someone from abusing your classes' implementations, at least it does clarify your intent, and documents such behavior as being *wrong* in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code sample. This will guide you:

```
public render(): void{ 

this.domElement.innerHTML = ` <div class="form-group">
   <input type="search" placeholder="Search the data" id="idSearch"/>
</div>`; 
this._setButtonEventHandlers(); 

}

private _setButtonEventHandlers(): void {
   const webPart: SpfxCrudWebPart = this;
   this.domElement.querySelector('#idSearch').addEventListener('click', () => {
      this._clickedMe();
   });
}


private _clickedMe(): void {
   console.log('clicked Me');
}
```